# A group and an associated digraph

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

I am trying to understand the proof of the following statement:

> Let $\Gamma=\{g_1,\cdots,g_n\}$ be a group. Define a digraph $G$ by
>   joining $g_i$ to $g_j$ by an edge of color $k$ if $g_ig_j^{-1}=g_k$.
>   The automorphism group of the resulting colored digraph is isomorphic
>   to $\Gamma$.

The proof in the [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821842625), constructs a map $\phi:\Gamma\to Aut(G)$ defined by $\phi(g)=f_g$ where $f_g\in Aut(G)$ such that $f_g(g_i)=g_ig$. Then it shows that $\phi$ is bijective.

The next sentence in the book (and the sentence I have a problem with) is:

> Since it is easy to see that the multiplication of elements of
>   $\Gamma$ is the same as multiplication between the corresponding
>   automorphisms of $G$, we conclude that the automorphism group of $G$
>   is isomorphic with $\Gamma$.

Obviously the meaning here is that $\phi$ is a homomorphism. However, I don't understand why $\phi(g_ig_j)=\phi(g_i)\circ\phi(g_j)$. Indeed, $f_{g_ig_j}(g_k)=g_kg_ig_j\ne g_kg_jg_i=f_{g_i}\circ f_{g_j}(g_k)$, and so $\phi(g_ig_j)\ne\phi(g_i)\circ\phi(g_j)$, in general.

Can someone explain please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $2$ kinds of mathematicians: one that writes composition of functions from right to left, and one from left to right.

If you instead consider the (other) $\phi$ acting *from the left*: $\phi(g)= x\mapsto gx$, then all is going to fit again. Or, alternatively, instead of $\circ$ you can think about its dual operation in $Aut(G)$.

And, it also might be a typo ['$f_g(g_i)=gg_i$'], or the book uses something in the other direction.

Finally, *among groups*, it doesn't really matter, because if we have such a 'contravariant' homomorphism, i.e. which satisfies
$$\phi(ab)=\phi(b)\phi(a)$$
then the mapping $x\mapsto \phi(x)^{-1}$ will be an ordinary group homomorphism, preserving the direction of the group operation.